# How to tell my background to overflow the container?

Tags: css

Ok, I want to display some text next to my pricetables. This text has a background that must be repeated across the entire page, thus outside the container. Atm, the text is behind it's background (thus not visible), and the background gets cutted at the edge of the container.

How can I edit this code so that I can see my text, and that the background overflows the edge of the container?

This is how it looks like right now:

[preview http://piclair.com/data/1t2ri.jpg](http://piclair.com/data/1t2ri.jpg)

My CSS:

```
.overflow {
margin:0 -400px;/* now equals 1600px wide */
min-height:213px;
background: url('/images/pakkettenbg.png') repeat-x;
position:relative;
z-index: 0;
overflow: visible;
}

#onside {position: relative; z-index: 1; margin-top: 124px; color: #8C8C8B;} 
#logopakketten {position: relative; z-index: 1; margin-left: 158px; margin-top: -332px; min-width: 782px; overflow: visible;} 
#orderbuttons {position: relative; z-index: 1; float: left; margin-left: 158px;}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="overflow">
<div id="onside">
<p>Unieke logo ontwerpen:</p>
<p>Levertijd:</p>
<p>Revisies:</p>
<p>Briefpapier ontwerpen:</p>
<p>Enveloppe ontwerpen:</p>
<p>Visitekaartje ontwerpen:</p>
<p>Bestandsformaten:</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="logopakketten">
<img src="/images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20S.png" alt="" /> 
<img src="/images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20M.png" alt="" /> 
<img src="/images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20L.png" alt="" /> 
<img src="/images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20XXL.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="orderbuttons">
<a href="#"><img src="/images/logopakketten/ordernow.png" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/images/logopakketten/ordernow.png" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/images/logopakketten/ordernow.png" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/images/logopakketten/ordernowlastcolumn.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That will get the background in front of the pricetables

Comment: That doesn't do anything m8, sorry. The Z-index of #onside was already 1 while the z-index from .overflow was 0.

Comment: it would be nice if you can share jsfiddle

Comment: what is the use of `* html .overflow {height:1px}`? It would be the same as `.overflow {height:1px}` and you just set `min-height:213px;`. ..

Comment: Hmm good point. Actually it does nothing useful anymore. I will remove it :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using positioning? That's a rhetorical question, you're not supposed to (use positioning). It's the jQuery of CSS, everyone uses it and it's the worst thing you can use.

If the child elements are floating than the parent needs to have `overflow: auto;` set. Also do not start relative URLs with a slash. You should get used to using the `base` element...

http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/streamlining-local-and-live-development-with-the-base-element

The main element with the repeating grey background-image should contain those vertical banners. You want text to the left of those banners? Then put text to the left of those banners.

You did not post enough to warrant a full working demo (reply with more info and I might be able to refine this for you) though this will get you moving and grooving in the right direction. Make sure you adjust the base element accordingly (it will be different for your local/live environments, use a scripting language like PHP to determine your domain (e.g. localhost or example.com) and *then* serve the correct value for the base element).

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']))
{
 if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'application/xhtml+xml'))
 {
  header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml');
 }
 else {header('Content-Type: text/html');}
}
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<base href="http://localhost/version-3.0/" />
<style type="text/css">
.overflow {overflow: auto;}
.left {float: left;}
.width_10 {width: 10%;}
.width_20 {width: 20%;}
.width_30 {width: 30%;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="overflow">

<div class="left">
 <p>text here</p>
</div>

<div class="vbanner">
<img src="images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20S.png" alt="" /> 
</div>

<div class="vbanner">

<img src="images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20M.png" alt="" /> 
</div>

<div class="vbanner">
<img src="images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20L.png" alt="" /> 
</div>

<div class="vbanner">
<img src="images/logopakketten/Prijskolom%20XXL.png" alt="" />
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Save this as an .xhtml extension if you're not using scripting (e.g. PHP) (XHTML will not work in IE8 or lower but it's at 5% market share right now, at this stage of your understanding concentrate on competent browsers) and XHTML is great because it's strict the moment you encounter an error you'll know you need to fix it, unless you want to blow three days trying to figure out you're missing a quote on an attribute. Strict code means you'll get in to the groove of doing it right the first time once you're used to it and it'll save you immense amounts of time.

You could also probably stand to learn how to correctly utilize CSS level 1, not a joke, most people don't correctly use the `float` property and end up spamming tons of `position` properties all over the place turning a page in to suck.

http://www.jabcreations.com/web/css/nested-divisible-elements

Yeah, you'll eventually utilize `position` for certain main-level elements for sites with advanced layouts (hint: 99% of sites do NOT have advanced layouts) but without a good foundation everything laying on top of that will be even less sturdy to relay on.

Comment: Hi @John. Z-index only works on positioned elements. That's why I use position: relative in this case. I try to use position as little as possible. Also, the links start with a / because I removed information in front of them.

Comment: I will learn from your examples now. Please give me moment to read it all :)

Comment: No problem, I check back time to time as I have question a two usually pending.